# Convert Hex to IP inline query

Tags: sql-server

Problem is i want to write an inline query to convert hexcode to ip format but I am getting the wrong result

I've am trying to write a query that converts the hex to ip but the result I am getting is wrong

```
SELECT DNS_SERVER1,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR,
         c.DNS_SERVER1/16777216)+'.'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, c.DNS_SERVER1/65535 % 256)+'.'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, c.DNS_SERVER1/256 % 256)+'.'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, c.DNS_SERVER1 % 256) as DNS_SERVER1_CONVERTED
FROM SEPMAdmin.SEM_COMPUTER AS c
```

Using the query above and an example data of "86921E34", I should get a "134.146.30.52" but what I am getting is "-121.-110.-225.-204"

Comment: How is DNS_SERVER1 data stored ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this...

```
DECLARE @hex_val binary(4) = 0x86921E34;

SELECT 
    ip_address = CONCAT(
            CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(@hex_val, 1,1)), '.',
            CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(@hex_val, 2,1)), '.',
            CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(@hex_val, 3,1)), '.',
            CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(@hex_val, 4,1))
            );
```

Result...

```
ip_address
---------------------------------------------------
134.146.30.52
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working. but can you explain to me what is happening in this code  so I can understand it better?

Comment: @MichaelRosello, Sure, your hex value is simply 4 one byte numbers put together. Each byte is represented by two characters (0-F) giving possible values of 0-255 for each byte... {0x86 = 134, 0x92 = 146, 0x1E = 30, 0x34 = 52}... The code above simply uses the SUBSTRING function to separate each byte. Each byte is then converted into its INT equivalent. The CONCAT() function simply converts all of the INTs to VARCHARs and appends everything together into a properly formatted string.